# Using a hyperlink to open a windows form

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to use a hyperlink on a local html page to open a windows form in C#. I've experimented around and one of my friends suggested trying this:

```
string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string url;
url = ("file:///" + curDir + "/startpage.html" + "#accounts");
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url);
if (webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri == url)
{
    Users u = new Users(this);
    u.Show();
}
```

What's the best way to approach this? As of now, this code doesn't do anything when I click the hyperlink, even though the url does change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By design, you cannot run an executable from a browser application as it would be a horrible security fail. Having said that, Using an ActiveX component in the browser would allow to run an arbitrary executable -- this is why ActiveX in the browser has been such a security problem.

ADDED RESPONSE

If you think about it you will also see that that Opening a local file is blocked by the browser for the same security reason. The exception will be that the when the open page is itself a local file, the browser will allow another open file. This may be browser dependent, but I don't think any modern common browser will allow it, though they may allow you to do so via a configuration option or a browser extension.

Comment: It's not an executable I'm running. I'm trying to use the web browser control within my program to open another form, still in the same project.

Comment: I don't see where you assign the URL to a hyperlink control

Comment: Well, I have in my HTML page a hyperlink that leads to "#accounts" which changes the URL by adding #accounts to the end. I was just trying to detect if the url matched and then open my form.

Comment: I already have the local HTML file working properly, I just want a hyperlink within that html to open another form. I'm not trying to open a local file, I'm just trying to open another within my program.